# How can I add multiple textbox values into database?

Tags: php

I'm building a script, when i click "add" it appears one more box, and when i click "remove", it removes the last box that i created.

The code is working perfectly but i want to add the information from those textboxes into my database, and i cant do it because my php script only reads the first textbox.

I just want to add all the information when i submit

how can i add multiple textbox values into my database?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--


    $(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;
    $("#add").click(function () {
    if(counter==11){
        alert("Too many boxes");
        return false;
    }   
        $("#textBoxes").append("<div id='d"+counter+"' ><label for='t2'> Textbox "+counter+"</label><input     type='textbox' id='t"+counter+"' > </div>\n");
        ++counter;
    });

    $("#remove").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
        alert("No boxes");
        return false;
    }   
        --counter;
        $("#d"+counter).remove();
    });
  });
// --></script>


</head><body>

 <div id='textBoxes'>
 <form method="POST">
<div id='d1' ><label for="t1"> Textbox 1</label><input name="nome" type='textbox' id='t1' ></div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='add' id='add'>
<input type='button' value='remove' id='remove'>
<input type='submit' name="adicionar" value='adicionar'>

</form>

<?php

 $dbHost = 'localhost';
            $dbUsername = 'hr';
            $dbPassword = '';
            $dbDatabase = 'r_inserir';

            $db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
            mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

if(isSet($_POST['adicionar']))
{

$nome=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nome']);

$sql=  mysql_query("INSERT INTO registos(nome) values ('".$nome."')");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your sql statement to include more data.

```
$nome=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nome']);
$snome=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['snome']);

$sql=  mysql_query("INSERT INTO registos(nome,snome) values ('".$nome."','".$snome."')");
```

Need to ensure that your database has these extra columns first too.

Then just add another box to your HTML

```
<input name="snome" type="textbox">
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but your answer doesnt work, thats not what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

```
    You need to give the same name to all the input boxes.  In your code it would be:
      name="nome"

    I notice that you are giving different id to the input boxes, which is good. But in your dynamically generated input boxes you are missing the name attribute for the input boxes.  Once you have this fixed.

    You could access the input boxes array like this:

    $names = $_POST['nome'];


    foreach( $names as $key => $n ) {
         $name=$n;
//sql query to insert into the db
    }
```